# XML element creation with colon with out attribute or any other namespaces C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to create xml like below

```
<author seq="1">
<ce:initials>M.</ce:initials>
<ce:surname>Beyer</ce:surname>
<ce:given-name>Michael</ce:given-name>
<ce:e-address>michael.beyer@uni-rostock.de</ce:e-address>
</author>
```

for that i used following code

```
  XNamespace ns = "ce";
        XElement XEinital = new XElement(ns +  "initials",initalarray[1] + ".",
                            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ce", ns));
```

but i got out put like following

```
 <ce:initials xmlns:ce="ce">M.</ce:initials>
```

but i need only element like below

```
<ce:initials>M.</ce:initials>
```

i need to remove attribute? is it possible?

Comment: i tried those things but i did't get

Comment: XNamespace ns = "ce";
            XElement XEinital = new XElement(ns + "initials", initalarray[1] + ".");  i tried this one. but i am getting    <initials xmlns="ce">M.</initials> this one. i need <ce:initals>M. </ce:initals>